# How deal with query handlers as dependency?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Iam building bounded context using CQRS pattern. I prepared some queries and handlers for each. And now, in presentation layer(http REST controller) I have to use it. Question is, should I inject each handler to this controller (there is 4 queries and handlers) or use command bus and configure right handlers to specified query?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your intention. Handling queries via the command bus is not really the idea behind CQRS. So usually, you have a command bus for submitting commands and separate read models (that are updated after commands have been executed) for handling queries (that do not alter the state of the system). What are your query handlers doing?

Answer (score 2):

Well, either way seems like it makes sense; that's probably a hint that you should be passing in an *interface* that expresses the contract that the Controller needs satisfied, and punt the implementation details down a level.

My guess is that you ultimately won't want the controller directly wired into the query handlers, because that will restrict your options in a number of use cases (example: congestion control and back pressure).  But you won't know until much further down the road, so keep things loose.

Answer (score -1):

In the past we've injected some sort of Query Executor into the controller and passed queries into that. eg,

```
public SomeController(IQueryExecutor queryExecutor) { ...
```

and then

```
var results = queryExecutor.Query(new GetSomeThings(args..));
```

The handler for `GetSomeThings` is wired up by the supporting infrastructure so you don't need to inject those. Does that make sense?

---

A word of warning about CQRS/CQS:

If you find you writing queries and handlers that are used at most only once or twice, or commands that are dedicated to the controller that uses them, then perhaps CQRS/CQS is an abstraction you don't actually need to be paying the extra complexity cost for.

My teams and I have found this to be true on a number of projects. Often CQRS/CQS is just another unnecessary abstraction like a Repository which dispatches to an ORM lib or a 'Service' which has one or two line dispatches to a Repository, which...
Hopefully you get the point.

I like the [Rule Of Three](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rule-of-three/) - don't try to get reusability until you have more than 3 usages. And even then, don't jump deep into something heavy and very prescribed like CQRS/CQS if you don't need it. DDD is very kool but you can pick and choose which elements of it make sense for you. Often much of it won't make sense when you apply pragmatic reasoning.

Just my 2 c.

Comment: CQS is a design principle, **not** an abstraction. CQRS is the result of applying CQS to a model, again **not** an abstraction. A model (any model) is an abstraction, the code is the implementation of that abstraction. Not to be confused with implementation details like interfaces or abstract classes.

Comment: @MikeSW It's *also* an abstraction in the context of a ORM. If I have an ORM interface which let's me issue commands and queries easily and then I wrap those up in some sort of CQS implementation, then it's another abstraction. That's all I was saying. If you have no ORM and you're building adonet from scratch, for example, then perhaps the abstraction (as part of the design principal implementation) is less but still there.

Comment: It's just a principle which doesn't care about ORMs, since a design principle shouldn't care about an implementation detail. I think you've misunderstood what CQS/CQRS are.

Comment: @MikeSW It seems you're not interested in helping the OP. While I respect definitions and semantic accuracy, in actuality the OP is asking for implementation help. So my answer was targeted to the context of common CQS implementations. Perhaps you should share some of your extensive knowledge and experience in a pragmatic way and offer an answer rather than argumentative banter over "right and wrong".